# "File Does Not Exist" when dynamically creating files for PDF download with Requests in Python 2.7

Tags: python, file-io, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to dynamically download pdf's from a web site.  I am sure I'm listing them correctly but I am not sure I'm doing the actual file I/O correctly.  I get the following error

```
  File "download.py", line 22, in <module>
    with open("'"+url+"'", "wb") as pdf:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'http://www.lcs.mit.edu/publications/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-179.pdf'"
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
origin = requests.get("http://freehaven.net/anonbib")
soup=BeautifulSoup(origin.text) 
results = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("(http).*(pdf)"))
for link in results:
    url = (link.get('href'))
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open("'"+url+"'", "wb") as pdf:
        try:
            pdf.write(r.content)
        finally:
            pdf.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `url` is set to `'http://www.lcs.mit.edu/publications/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-179.pdf'`, your code fails because it is trying to open a file with that name on your filesystem.

Instead, try something like this:

```
fileForUrl = '/tmp/' + url.split('/')[-1]
with open(fileForUrl, 'wb') as pdf:
   # Rest of the code as before
```